# How to set wordpress url on local host to access it via VPN

Tags: urls, sql

I have an issue. I have wordpress installed on raspberry PI that is connected to my home local network. I have a conenction to this pi via hamachi VPN. The issue is that in SQL database there is url set to pi local IP which is http://192.168.1.56. When i connect through browser using hamachi virtual IP my browser resolves it as http://192.168.1.56 which is not available on my work network. How to set url so that it can be accesed through hamachi?

Comment: Do you have a DNS name you can use for this, that you can split between the internal and external addresses depending on where you're accessing it from? If you can't, you could add code to wp-config to spot if it's being accessed by the Himachi URL and define WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to match that to trick WordPress into thinking it's on the correct address and not trying to redirect, but then you might run into problems with URLs for media embedded in posts. You'd do better trying to set something up with DNS.

Comment: But this is the same sort of problem you'd have running WordPress behind a reverse proxy, so you might find help in documentation for that. (Although a fair amount of that will cover SSL termination which isn't your issue here.)